# Ubuntu colors changed

Tags: 15.04, appearance

Something tells me that I hit a keyboard shortcut I'm not aware of, but many of my colors changed. The icons in the upper-right (wifi, b/t, time, etc) are now white, along with the text at the top of a maximized application (app title) and the bars at the tops of windows. My terminal has also switched into a white and black mode from the default purple. How can I get it back? I do remember using my Chrome browser when it started zooming crazily, perhaps it was around that time that I enabled some hidden accessibility mode?

EDIT: My software center has also switched to a brighter mode.

EDIT2: It looks like white text and icons are being laid over the original ones in the window title bar.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uninstalling a package (probably nginx), the default Ambience theme was lost. I restored it by issuing the following command then rebooting:

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have accidentally enable High Contrast mode "For the vision impaired". To turn this off, follow these steps.

1. Right-click on the Ubuntu desktop
2. Click "Change Desktop Background"
3. When the settings window appears, click the drop-down menu next to "Theme"
4. Select "Ambience *(default)*"

If the "Ambience *(default)*" theme is not available in the drop-down menu, type
 `sudo apt-get install light-themes`
into the terminal, and check again.

Comment: The Ambience theme is missing from that list. Only "High Contrast" is available, but high contrast is truly enabled when I click it in the dropdown (only option). Otherwise the box is just left blank.

Comment: It looks like when I uninstalled nginx, the Ambience theme was also deleted from my system.

Comment: Try _sudo apt-get install Unity_ and see if it says that the Ambiance theme is missing.

Comment: I issued _sudo apt-get install light-themes_ and Ambiance reappeared in the list. I can't quite figure out why it would have disappeared.

Comment: Maybe it was just a glitch, I've had problems with themes in the past as well. Is the problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a keyboard shortcut for it, but it sounds a lot like "High Contrast" mode.  System Settings - Universal Access - High Contrast

Comment: "High Contrast" mode is disabled. When changing my theme in the desktop background window, the only available option appears to be "High Contrast" but only when selected does the high contrast feature become enabled.

Comment: It looks like when I uninstalled nginx, the Ambience theme was also deleted from my system.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, that you install all Ubuntu themes again, start the command below

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop-next
```

or at least

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-artwork
```